# Multiple div's with vertical text

Tags: html, css

I want preferably a setup with divs instead of working with a table and can't figure out how 
In a table it would be close to this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/la2hdfa9

But neither with DIV and vertical text nor with tables and vertical text I can get a proper solution. 
The vertical text should be aligned to the bottom

Any advice, please edit.
Thank you very much

Comment: No one can edit this and provide the code you attempted this with but you.

Comment: Flexbox is your friend.

Comment: can you put your codes here in a snippet and clarify your question ?

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve but evenly distributed and proper aligned. It ca be a table or with div. That does not really matter to me. https://jsfiddle.net/lucullus/6un9vvrc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transform do rotate a div, however it should be positioned absolute and then set the top and left accordingly:

```css
.verticaltext {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right, top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:right, top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:right, top;
    position: absolute; 
    color: #ed217c;
    top: 20%;
}

.first {
    left: 20px;
 }

.second {
    left: 40px;
 }

.third {
    left: 60px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="verticaltext first">
  This is a vertical text
 </div>

<div class="verticaltext second">
  This is a vertical text
 </div>

<div class="verticaltext third">
  This is a vertical text
 </div>
```

UPDATE:

This can be done with flex as well:

```css
.header,
.footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.inside {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-width: 0;  
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.test:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be challenging in terms of positioning. When you look at https://jsfiddle.net/lucullus/6un9vvrc/ you see where I need to get to. Any other ideas?

Comment: Seems like something I can take as a basis.